# Mystery WordPress archive template

Tags: wordpress, debugging, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need your help! Do you have any idea what's going on?
I have following code:

```
<div id="post-list">
3
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
1
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="article-inner <?php flatsome_blog_article_classes(); ?>">
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/posts/partials/entry-header', flatsome_option('blog_posts_header_style') ); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/posts/content', 'default' ); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/posts/partials/entry-footer', 'default' ); ?>
    </div><!-- .article-inner -->
</article><!-- #-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
2
<?php endwhile; ?>
4

<?php flatsome_posts_pagination(); ?>

</div>
```

Do you see that numbers 4321? So, problem that when I go to single author posts archive page I see only 3 and 4 (that's mean code inside while not work for it but I can see all posts, just in different template), BUT when I open some category page with posts listing — it's show me all numbers in following order: 3124 that's mean that everything working how it's should be. This code in archive.php file. I need setup the same template for authors posts and category listings. Thank you!

Comment: Google "wordpress template hierarchy", there's a nice infographic explaining it. Btw, very confusing the way you described your problem...

Comment: I know hierarchy, it's in the same file! May be I described it's not so clear, but it's exactly this file who show this two lists.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking here - do you mean "why aren't my author archive posts not showing when the same template file is showing category archive posts?"

Comment: This code in file archive.php that applies to authors archive and categories archive, I don't have any other files that can be used instead of, so it's definitely only this one file which show posts list for this two cases, but, when I try to debug this file — I see that for category it's working (show all numbers), but for authors archive — it's show only first and last number, and If I remove this 'while' loop — everywhere posts will not show, that's mean that is exactly this file and I don't have any other files that make impact to template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in that it have this plugin https://toolset.com/ that overwrite some templates and store all code in database.